# How to waterproof your shoes?

Tags: clothing, weather, shoes

Are there any home ways to coat your shoes (made of material like canvas or cotton) to be water resistance?

Some time ago I've tried [Ultra Ever Dry](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEH6tDLKcVU#t=176), but it was too smelly, toxic and the coating layer was too visible.

Comment: Duncan: Yes, canvas or cotton.

Comment: Can you please tell us what you have tried and why that didn't work?

Comment: @michaelpri I've tried [Ultra Ever Dry](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEH6tDLKcVU#t=176) once, but it was too smelly and toxic. I didn't tried any other methods than a wax (if there are some).

Comment: Related: http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1673/is-there-any-way-to-fill-in-a-hole-in-my-shoe-so-it-is-waterproof?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to polish your shoes with wax.

Rub the beeswax over the entirety of the shoe. Use dishwashing gloves or rubber gloves to keep your hands clean.

If you don't have beeswax, use the candle wax.

When finish, optionally you can use your hair dryer (with high heat) to eliminate the whitish color (so the wax will melt into material even deeper).

[image: How to waterproof your shoes]

See also:

- (video) [How to Make Your Shoes Waterproof](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnFQy49mank) by CrazyRussianHacker

Answer (score 1):

Try spraying a thin film of nano paint(buckysome) on your shoes. As this makes your shoes super proof(the paint doesn't allow any particles reside on it). Goodluck my friend,:).